# Spring MVC Service Beans loaded twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with my Spring MVC application where my @Service classes are being created twice. I found few threads discussing this issue and most of the time it's related to have the `<context:component-scan />` defined both in the Application and also Servlet Context. But in my case I have all the configuration in the Application Context file and the Servlet Context conf file is empty. I'm including the `web.xml` and the `applicationContext.xml` files.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />        
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <task:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.app" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/WEB-INF/assets/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>

    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
        <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
          <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
        </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="viewNames" value="thymeleaf/*" />
    </bean>

      <mvc:interceptors>
        <!-- Changes the locale when a 'locale' request parameter is sent; e.g. 
        /?locale=de -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
      </mvc:interceptors>
      <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="cookieName" value="myCookie" />
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="sk_SK" />
      </bean>


    <import resource="spring/spring-security.xml"/>     
    <import resource="spring/data-source.xml" />
    <import resource="spring/lang-source.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/data-properties.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/data-managers.xml" />
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>300</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Is it really empty or is it importing configurations? Also make sure you aren't creating instances of the context yourself in your code. Just wondering how are you checking the duplicate bean creation? When using class based proxies it appears as if duplicate instances are created...

Comment: Yes the servlet conf is empty without imports. I'm autowiring all the service beans in my code so there is no additional instance creation. And I use logging for the Services that's have I know about the duplicity. And I'm sure that the logging implementation isn't a problem as I see some business methods are also execute twice.

Comment: There is no reason that when there are 2 instances that a method would also execute twice (unless you use a scheduler which is also started twice). So isn't the problem with the loggin? I also wasn't mentioning instance creation but creation of an `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: You don't have, by accident, have a `WebApplicationInitializer` next to your `web.xml`?

Comment: If your `servlet-context.xml` is empty then why have an XML file anyway. When specifying an empty `<param-value>` here it will construct an empty `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Hi @M. Deinum, sorry for the late reply and thx for you effort. Actually I found the issue and it was related to logging implementation that I use for the application. I resolved it and everything works now.

Answer (score -3):

If you use spring mvc. There will be two context in your application. the spring context which is based on applicationContext.xml and the appServlet-servlet.xml(the name is based on your servlet name appServlet).

When the spring context init, it will component-scan your package defined in applicationContext.xml. It is the first time your service created.
Then when you use DispatcherServlet, it will create a spring context. If you have appServlet-servlet.xml, it is based on this. if else, it will component-scan all your classpath. It is the second time your service created.

If you don't want it, you can write it in your applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.app">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

And then you should create appServlet-servlet.xml and write component-scan like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.app" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

So you can hold all your compontent and service in your spring context. And spring mvc will just hold the controller.

Comment: The OP already stated the context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` is empty and as such it doesn't load anything. Next to that your code is flawed as the one loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` should include a `use-default-filters="false"` as at the moment it is scanning for everything.

Comment: If it doesn't load anything, all controllers will not work to handler the request. So I think it is component-scan its package to create the controllers.

Comment: No it isn't it scans for everything not only controllers.

Comment: the application-context will make it scans for everything, of course contains controllers. but at this time dispatcher servlet can not get the controllers. So it will not work to handler the request. I think OP get the web application worked. So it must be mvc sacn the package to get controllers. What if it also scan the service?

Comment: The OP question is about loading beans twice. The code you post will result in duplicate loading of all beans other than `@Controller`. This will cause havoc especially if you have a `<tx:annotation-driven />` or the likes in the root. Suddenly poof no transactions.

Comment: I can not understand why my code will result in duplicate loading of all beans other than @Controller. the spring context create the beans of @ Service and @ conpomnent. The mvc context create the beans of @ Controller. Do I have some mistake about the code?

Comment: The mvc context creates all beans... There is no exclusion and as such the defaults of scanning for all `@Component` related annotation still applies. You must add a `use-default-filters="false"` to disable the defaults and only scan for `@Controllers` as I specified in my initial argument.

Comment: Oh, yes, I lost the `use-default-filters="false"`